# Vue won't accept the colon in my code after options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, options: {
  load: {
    key: ''
  },
  installComponents: false
}
```

Vue keeps telling me that the ":" after options is wrong and it expects a ",". I was following along to a tutorial about adding geolocating maps and I followed it exactly. It accepted his code, but won't take mine. Is there something wrong with the way I've set it up? I'm using Vue/Cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the label 'options'...pls check the modified code below

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: ''
  },
  installComponents: false
})
```

To know more about vue2-google-maps please check the below link..
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps